# How to run REP and PUB in single instance non-blocking Pyzmq

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

My object:

```
class mysrv(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._pubsocket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
        self._socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
        self._socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:9003")
        self._pubsocket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:9004")
```

Then I run both functions:

```
def main():
    s = mysrv()
    Process(target=s.publoop()).start()
    Process(target=s.reqrep()).start()
```

The first function blocks the second. Is there any way to run them from a single class instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that `while` will block everything even `sleep` is called.

So, running many `whiles` in the same process without breaks is blocking.